# How can I change the custom fetch header in Next.js middleware?

Tags: next.js, cookies, fetch, middleware

I'm contemplating how to add cookies to the headers during server-side rendering (SSR) in Next.js.

Currently, I've created a custom API module as shown below to simplify the use of fetch.

```
// custom-api.ts
export const headers = new Headers({
    credentials: 'include',
});

const api = {
    get: async(path: string, options?: any) => {
        const res = await fetch(`${path}`, {
                headers,
                ...options,
            });

        return await res.json();
    },
```

The issue is that when sending requests with SSR, I have to set the headers each time in getServerSideProps, which becomes cumbersome.

```
// import { getData } from '@/services/main';
export getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
    const { cookies } = context.req;

    const queryClient = new QueryClient();
    queryClient.prefetchQuery([query-key], getData)
```

Therefore, I attempted to handle this in a middleware, but the modified headers are not being applied to the requests. What could be the reason for this?

```
//src/middleware.ts
import { headers } from '@/utils/api';
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const { cookies } = request;
    headers.set('Cookie', `my-cookie=${cookies.get('my-cookie')?.value); //The values are properly being inserted
    NextResponse.next();
```